# displaying news in css next to each other

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following design with `css` and `html`. I need to display the 'post' divs next to each other. `display:block;` is not working, I have tried many things.

This I my code:

```css
#content {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0;
}

#dummy {
  padding-top: 29%;
}

#content .post {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 15px 0 35px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 2px;
}

#content .post h2 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#content .post h2 a {
  color: #252525;
}

#content .post .date {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #808080;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#content .post .continue {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #DC1000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: left;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#content .post p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

#content .post .thumb div {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content .post .thumb img {
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <!-- begin post -->
  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="#">A crut tellus et Gravida Ipsum</a></h2>

    <div class="thumb"><img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" />
      <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /></div>

    <p class="date">Posted on January 7, 2008 by admin</p>
    <p> Viverra integer enim, sed dolor. Inceptos elit, vitae et. Eget eget nec, lectus nisl, vehicula est feugiat. cum condimentum mattis dui fusce ut, vel convallis suspendisse suspendisse sed in. Libero blandit curae at magna ut, id mauris suspendisse
      ligula neque integer non.</p>
    <a class="continue" href="#">Continue Reading</a> </div>
  <div id="dummy">
  </div>
  <!-- end post -->
  <!-- begin post -->
  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="#">A crut tellus et Gravida Ipsum</a></h2>

    <div class="thumb"><img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" />
      <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /> <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /></div>

    <p class="date">Posted on January 7, 2008 by admin</p>
    <p> Viverra integer enim, sed dolor. Inceptos elit, vitae et. Eget eget nec, lectus nisl, vehicula est feugiat. cum condimentum mattis dui fusce ut, vel convallis suspendisse suspendisse sed in. Libero blandit curae at magna ut, id mauris suspendisse
      ligula neque integer non.</p>
    <a class="continue" href="#">Continue Reading</a> </div>
  <!-- end post -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use flex by changing the CSS of `#content` by this :

```
#content {
  display:flex;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Here is the full code (i also removed a usless float property)

```css
/** BEGIN content **/

#content {
  display:flex;
  margin: 0;
}


#content .post {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 15px 0 35px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 2px;
}

#content .post h2 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#content .post h2 a {
  color: #252525;
}

#content .post .date {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #808080;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#content .post .continue {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #DC1000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: left;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#content .post p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

#content .post .thumb div {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content .post .thumb img {
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <!-- begin post -->
  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="#">A crut tellus et Gravida Ipsum</a></h2>

    <div class="thumb"><img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" />
      <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /></div>

    <p class="date">Posted on January 7, 2008 by admin</p>
    <p> Viverra integer enim, sed dolor. Inceptos elit, vitae et. Eget eget nec, lectus nisl, vehicula est feugiat. cum condimentum mattis dui fusce ut, vel convallis suspendisse suspendisse sed in. Libero blandit curae at magna ut, id mauris suspendisse
      ligula neque integer non.</p>
    <a class="continue" href="#">Continue Reading</a> </div>
  <div id="dummy">
  </div>
  <!-- end post -->
  <!-- begin post -->
  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="#">A crut tellus et Gravida Ipsum</a></h2>

    <div class="thumb"><img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" />
      <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /> <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /></div>

    <p class="date">Posted on January 7, 2008 by admin</p>
    <p> Viverra integer enim, sed dolor. Inceptos elit, vitae et. Eget eget nec, lectus nisl, vehicula est feugiat. cum condimentum mattis dui fusce ut, vel convallis suspendisse suspendisse sed in. Libero blandit curae at magna ut, id mauris suspendisse
      ligula neque integer non.</p>
    <a class="continue" href="#">Continue Reading</a> </div>
  <!-- end post -->
</div>
```

You can also control the number of element in the same row by controlling the `flex` property of child elements. here is an example with 4 elements and 2 in each row.

Here is the code you have to add :

```
#content .post {
  flex:0 0 50%; /* this mean take half the space of the row*/
}
```

You also need to pay attention to overflow that's why i added this code :

```
* {
      box-sizing:border-box;
  }
```

Read more about [box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

You need also to setup [flex-wrap](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp) property like this :

```
#content {
  display:flex;
  margin: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* this allow line break */
}
```

```css
/** BEGIN content **/
body,html {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#content {
  display:flex;
  margin: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


#content .post {
  text-align: left;
  flex:0 0 50%;
  padding: 20px 15px 0 35px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;

}

#content .post h2 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#content .post h2 a {
  color: #252525;
}

#content .post .date {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #808080;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#content .post .continue {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #DC1000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: left;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#content .post p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

#content .post .thumb div {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content .post .thumb img {
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <!-- begin post -->
  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="#">A crut tellus et Gravida Ipsum</a></h2>

    <div class="thumb"><img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" />
      <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /></div>

    <p class="date">Posted on January 7, 2008 by admin</p>
    <p> Viverra integer enim, sed dolor. Inceptos elit, vitae et. Eget eget nec, lectus nisl, vehicula est feugiat. cum condimentum mattis dui fusce ut, vel convallis suspendisse suspendisse sed in. Libero blandit curae at magna ut, id mauris suspendisse
      ligula neque integer non.</p>
    <a class="continue" href="#">Continue Reading</a> </div>
  <!-- end post -->
    <!-- begin post -->
  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="#">A crut tellus et Gravida Ipsum</a></h2>

    <div class="thumb"><img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" />
      <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /></div>

    <p class="date">Posted on January 7, 2008 by admin</p>
    <p> Viverra integer enim, sed dolor. Inceptos elit, vitae et. Eget eget nec, lectus nisl, vehicula est feugiat. cum condimentum mattis dui fusce ut, vel convallis suspendisse suspendisse sed in. Libero blandit curae at magna ut, id mauris suspendisse
      ligula neque integer non.</p>
    <a class="continue" href="#">Continue Reading</a> </div>
  <!-- end post -->
    <!-- begin post -->
  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="#">A crut tellus et Gravida Ipsum</a></h2>

    <div class="thumb"><img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" />
      <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /></div>

    <p class="date">Posted on January 7, 2008 by admin</p>
    <p> Viverra integer enim, sed dolor. Inceptos elit, vitae et. Eget eget nec, lectus nisl, vehicula est feugiat. cum condimentum mattis dui fusce ut, vel convallis suspendisse suspendisse sed in. Libero blandit curae at magna ut, id mauris suspendisse
      ligula neque integer non.</p>
    <a class="continue" href="#">Continue Reading</a> </div>
  <!-- end post -->
  <!-- begin post -->
  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="#">A crut tellus et Gravida Ipsum</a></h2>

    <div class="thumb"><img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" />
      <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /> <img height="100" src="fdb.jpg" alt="" /></div>

    <p class="date">Posted on January 7, 2008 by admin</p>
    <p> Viverra integer enim, sed dolor. Inceptos elit, vitae et. Eget eget nec, lectus nisl, vehicula est feugiat. cum condimentum mattis dui fusce ut, vel convallis suspendisse suspendisse sed in. Libero blandit curae at magna ut, id mauris suspendisse
      ligula neque integer non.</p>
    <a class="continue" href="#">Continue Reading</a> </div>
  <!-- end post -->
</div>
```

Comment: but thats not the point I need to display for example two divs or three next to each other , and then switch to new line to start again

Comment: @gfdfgffgfdfg you can do this of course, am gonna update my anwser with more details ;)

Comment: @gfdfgffgfdfg check my answer again

Comment: @gfdfgffgfdfg check all my code please. In the CSS at the first line

Comment: @gfdfgffgfdfg i added more clarification, you are facing overflow issue

Comment: Thankyou , just one more question . Is there a way to display images more perfectly ?

Comment: @gfdfgffgfdfg make them `100%` width .. add in your CSS `img {width:100%}`

Comment: @gfdfgffgfdfg by the way it will depend what you mean by **perfectly**

Comment: I mean that  if I added more than one photo per post , I need their look to be good

Comment: @gfdfgffgfdfg it depends on how you want them to be shown. unfortunately **good** has no meaning as everyone see good things differently

Comment: ANYWAY i APPRECIATE YOUR HELP THANKS A LOT